# Cannot convert JSONArray to JSONObject using Volley

Tags: android, web-services, android-volley, android-json

I'm trying to use Volley for consuming a web service. This is my logcat output:

> 12-14 10:45:41.750: I/Annuaire2error(4005): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"label":[{"pers_nom":"yen","pers_id":"1","pers_prenom":"ines","pers_email":"yen98.ines@gmail.com","pers_phone":"443456784"},{"pers_nom":"Jamin","pers_id":"2","pers_prenom":" Derkok","pers_email":"jamin.drk23@gmail.com","pers_phone":"2345512398"}]}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

it seems that it can't access the value of `label` of my web service. How can I convert from `JSONArray` to `JSONObject`?

This is my code:

```
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.i(TAG,response.toString());
        try{
            JSONObject value = response.getJSONObject("label");
            String essai = value.getString("pers_nom");
            /**
             * just for check 
             * */
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+essai, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d("volley output", essai);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
},new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "errrrroooor", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        Log.i(TAG+"error",error.getMessage());
    }
});

mRequestQueue.add(jr);
```

Comment: please follow the below example to use volley: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-volley-library-example.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The response that you get is a JSONArray not a JSONObject

```
public void onResponse(JSONObject response)// resposne should be JSONArray
// Change it to JSONArray
```

This

```
JSONObject value = response.getJSONObject("label"); // wrong
// label is a json array
```

Your json

```
[ // json array node 
    { // json object node 
        "label": [ // json array label
            {
                "pers_nom": "yen",
                "pers_id": "1",
                "pers_prenom": "ines",
                "pers_email": "yen98.ines@gmail.com",
                "pers_phone": "443456784"
            },
            {
                "pers_nom": "Jamin",
                "pers_id": "2",
                "pers_prenom": " Derkok",
                "pers_email": "jamin.drk23@gmail.com",
                "pers_phone": "2345512398"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Should be something like

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
 Log.i(TAG,response.toString());
 try{
  JSONObject value = response.getJSONObject(0);
  JSONArray jr = value.getJSONArray("label");
  for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
  {
  JSONObject jb = (JSONObject) jr.get(i);
  String pers_nom = jb.getString("pers_nom"); 
  Log.i(".........",pers_nom);
  ...// similarly for id and so on..  
  }
  ...// rest of the code
```

Edit:

```
 Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener = new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
        {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };
        Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };
```

And use

```
    JsonArrayRequest  jr =new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url, listener, errorListener) ;
```

Edit 2:

I check the source and it looks like below

```
 public JsonArrayRequest(String url, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(Method.GET, url, null, listener, errorListener);

        }
```

Comment: so I'm making an error . what if I changed the web service format to this:
[{"pers_id":"1","pers_nom":"yen","pers_prenom":"ines","pers_email":"yen98.ines@gmail.com","pers_phone":"443456784"},{"pers_id":"2","pers_nom":"Jamin","pers_prenom":" Derkok","pers_email":"jamin.drk23@gmail.com","pers_phone":"2345512398"}] 
 it means without JsonArray!! but still get the same error.
my main question how can I get access to a webservice which hasn't a json array label???

Comment: its still a json array response. then json object and then jsons tring

Comment: @YenInes if you want to use json array like before check the edit and i found the docs here @ http://files.evancharlton.com/volley-docs/

Comment: @YenInes check the edit2. Make sure you use codes in Edit and keep the json as it is. Also use the parsing before edit section and it should work fine

Comment: I'm changing it all
wait please I'll show you what I get
thanks a lot

Comment: @ Raghunanda
I couldn't access to that link: files.evancharlton.com/volley-docs

Comment: @YenInes i can open. i have no problem to view the docs from here. Any way make the changes mentioned it should work without a problem. Some fire wall or restriction from your side i guess.

Comment: @ Raghunanda
Thanks a lot 
it works now ,thanks a lot,
you're genius 
you save me.thanks :)))) 
really you make me turn so happy  
thank you.
you can look at what I arrived to use in the edit code.
really thank you.

Comment: of course I accepted it & I upvoted too ,really I'm so happy thank you :))

Comment: @YenInes you are welcome and glad i could help you with your problem